# Begin a sentence with To+inf vs Gerund?

Tags: word-choice, infinitive-vs-gerund

> **To read** this book was my dream.
>
> **Reading** this book was my dream.

What is the difference between using “To read” and “Reading”?

When I have to use any of them? When they can not be interchangeable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Reading this book was my dream.

"Reading" refers to an action that was/is actually happening, or that the speaker is positive enough about that being true.

> To read this book was my dream.

"To read" refers to an action that was/is not actually happening, or *could not*/*may*/*might*/*should*/*would* (but didn't) happen.